# How can I toggle between tabs after I make an api call to populate them

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the api I was able to get the lists of articles that I need. My goal is to create a navigation tab that toggles between sections when clicked. (A section contains many articles)

```
<div class="tabs">
  <input type="radio" name="tabs-1" id="tabs-1-0" onclick="location.href='/homepage';">
  <label class="tabs__title" for="tabs-1-0">
    <span class="tabs__separator">
      Home
    </span>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="tabs-1" id="tabs-1-1" value="360003487117">
  <label class="tabs__title" for="tabs-1-1">
    <span class="tabs__separator">
      Potatoes
    </span>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="tabs-1" id="tabs-1-2" value="360003487177">
  <label class="tabs__title" for="tabs-1-2">
    <span class="tabs__separator">
      Mushrooms
    </span>
  </label>
  <div class="tabs__panel">
    <div class="tabs__panel__content">

    </div>
    <div class="tabs__panel__content">

    </div>
    <div class="tabs__panel__content">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I managed to get so far but I have some problems with making the toggle work. My problem here is that it simply adds up to the existing ones without removing the previous one.

````
      var sct_select = $( "input[type=radio][name=tabs-1]:checked" ).val();
      $.getJSON('/api/sections/'+ sct_select + '/articles.json', function(data) { 
        $.each(data.articles, function(index,item) {
          var style1 = '<p><a href="'+ item.html_url + '">' + item.title + '</a></p>'
           $('.tabs__panel__content').append(style1);
        
});
            $( ".tabs__panel__content" ).toggle( "slow" );
});
}); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

To have a sample functional you have to do some job to create tabs:  (this sample is not functional for home button because you have a click event in html)

by default, its always the first tabs displayed

```js
$( ".tabs__panel" ).tabs();
$("input.radioBtn").on("click", function () {
           var index = $("input.radioBtn").index(this);
      var sct_select = $(this).val();


      //toggle to the desired tab following the index of button clicked)
      $( ".tabs__panel" ).tabs({ active: index + 1 });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="tabs">
  <input type="radio" name="tabs-1" id="tabs-1-0" onclick="location.href='/homepage';">
  <label class="tabs__title" for="tabs-1-0">
    <span class="tabs__separator">
      Home
    </span>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="tabs-1" id="tabs-1-1" value="360003487117">
  <label class="tabs__title" for="tabs-1-1">
    <span class="tabs__separator">
      Potatoes
    </span>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="tabs-1" id="tabs-1-2" value="360003487177">
  <label class="tabs__title" for="tabs-1-2">
    <span class="tabs__separator">
      Mushrooms
    </span>
  </label>
  <div class="tabs__panel">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab0"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab1"><span>Potates</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2"><span>Mushrooms</span></a></li>
  </ul>
    <div class="tabs__panel__content" id="tab0">

    </div>
    <div class="tabs__panel__content" id="tab1">

    </div>
    <div class="tabs__panel__content" id="tab2">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but I keep getting an error that tabs() is not a function.