# How to toggle between input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to to add a toggle when a certain input is clicked (checked).

```
div class = "tabs-wrapper">
      <div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs-1" id="tabs-1-0" onclick="location.href='/h/en;">
    <label class="tabs__title  home_tabs" for="tabs-1-0">
      <span class="tabs__separator">
     <f-icon icon="home"></f-icon>   Home
      </span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" class = "radioBtn"  name="tabs-1" id="tabs-1-1" divId = "div1" value="360003487117">
    <label class="tabs__title" for="tabs-1-1">
      <span class="tabs__separator">
       <f-icon icon="monitor"></f-icon> Cat1 <f-icon icon="caret-down" class = "downNavArrow rotate-reset"></f-icon>
      </span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" class = "radioBtn"  name="tabs-1" id="tabs-1-2" divId = "div2" value="360003487177">
    <label class="tabs__title" for="tabs-1-2">
      <span class="tabs__separator">
       <f-icon icon="personal"></f-icon> Cat 2 <f-icon icon="caret-down" class = "downNavArrow rotate-reset"></f-icon>
      </span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" class = "radioBtn"  name="tabs-1" id="tabs-1-3" divId = "div3" value="360004539997">
    <label class="tabs__title" for="tabs-1-3">
      <span class="tabs__separator">
       <f-icon icon="ac-icon_participation"></f-icon> Cat 3 <f-icon icon="caret-down" class = "downNavArrow rotate-reset"></f-icon>
      </span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" class = "radioBtn"  name="tabs-1" id="tabs-1-4" divId = "div4" value="360003510518">
    <label class="tabs__title" for="tabs-1-4">
      <span class="tabs__separator">
       <f-icon icon="users"></e-icon> Cat 4 <f-icon icon="caret-down" class = "downNavArrow rotate-reset"></f-icon>
      </span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" class = "radioBtn"  name="tabs-1" id="tabs-1-5" divId = "div5" value="360003487197">
    <label class="tabs__title" for="tabs-1-5">
      <span class="tabs__separator">
        <f-icon icon="media-rich"></f-icon>Cat 5 <f-icon icon="caret-down" class = "downNavArrow rotate-reset"></f-icon>
      </span>
    </label>
    <div class="tabs__panel">
      <div class="tabs__panel__content" id = "div0">
   
      </div>
      <div class="tabs__panel__content" id = "div1">

      </div>
      <div class="tabs__panel__content" id = "div2">

      </div>
      <div class="tabs__panel__content" id = "div3">

      </div>
      <div class="tabs__panel__content" id = "div4">
   
      </div>
       <div class="tabs__panel__content" id = "div5">
   
      </div>
    </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

By making a get request I was able to pull all the information I need and display it in the corresponding tabs. In my code so far I am able to append the info to the tabs.I would like however to be able to toggle the information (hide and expand) whenever the "radioBtn" is clicked.Is there a better way to rewrite what I have tried below and also make that toggle work?
I also tried adding the toggle function inside the click function, but after doing that I was able to see the checkboxes on the website , checkboxes that were hidden by default.

```
function summonSct() {
$.getJSON('/api/center/cats/'+ sct_select + '/articles.json', function(data) { 
    $.each(data.articles, function(index,item) {
    var listArt = '<p><a href="'+ item.html_url + '">' + item.title + '</a></p>'
    $('.tabs__panel__content').append(listArt);
       $('.tabs__panel').show("slow");
});
});
}
$(".radioBtn").on("click", function() {
  var checkedIds = $(".radioBtn:checked").map(function() {
    return this.id;
  }).toArray();
  console.log(checkedIds);
        $('.tabs__panel').hide("slow");
        $('.tabs__panel__content').empty();
        summonSct(); 
});
```

Comment: i have done an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66347668/how-can-i-toggle-between-tabs-after-i-make-an-api-call-to-populate-them  and you havent give a comment..about that???

Comment: this is invalid `onclick="location.href='/h/en;"` since you are missing a `'`

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a radio button and not a checkbox I don't see the need for using `.map()` to get the id of the checkbox you clicked, you can just use `$(this).attr("id")`

*Note* In the solution below I've removed the ajax because we can't test that part.

```
function summonSct(id) {
  var n = id.split('-').pop()
  console.log('#div' + n + '.tabs__panel__content')
  $('#div' + n + '.tabs__panel__content').append(id);
  $('#div' + n + '.tabs__panel').show("slow");
}
$(".radioBtn").on("click", function() {
  var checkedIds = $(this).attr("id")
  console.log(checkedIds);
  $('.tabs__panel__content').empty();
  summonSct(checkedIds);
});
```

**Demo**

```js
function summonSct(id) {
  var n = id.split('-').pop()
  console.log('#div' + n + '.tabs__panel__content')
  $('#div' + n + '.tabs__panel__content').append(id);
  $('#div' + n + '.tabs__panel').show("slow");
}
$(".radioBtn").on("click", function() {
  var checkedIds = $(this).attr("id")
  console.log(checkedIds);
  $('.tabs__panel__content').empty();
  summonSct(checkedIds);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-wrapper">
  <div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs-1" id="tabs-1-0" onclick="location.href='/h/en;'">
    <label class="tabs__title  home_tabs" for="tabs-1-0">
      <span class="tabs__separator">
     <f-icon icon="home"></f-icon>   Home
      </span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="tabs-1" id="tabs-1-1" divId="div1" value="360003487117">
    <label class="tabs__title" for="tabs-1-1">
      <span class="tabs__separator">
       <f-icon icon="monitor"></f-icon> Cat1 <f-icon icon="caret-down" class = "downNavArrow rotate-reset"></f-icon>
      </span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="tabs-1" id="tabs-1-2" divId="div2" value="360003487177">
    <label class="tabs__title" for="tabs-1-2">
      <span class="tabs__separator">
       <f-icon icon="personal"></f-icon> Cat 2 <f-icon icon="caret-down" class = "downNavArrow rotate-reset"></f-icon>
      </span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="tabs-1" id="tabs-1-3" divId="div3" value="360004539997">
    <label class="tabs__title" for="tabs-1-3">
      <span class="tabs__separator">
       <f-icon icon="ac-icon_participation"></f-icon> Cat 3 <f-icon icon="caret-down" class = "downNavArrow rotate-reset"></f-icon>
      </span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="tabs-1" id="tabs-1-4" divId="div4" value="360003510518">
    <label class="tabs__title" for="tabs-1-4">
      <span class="tabs__separator">
       <f-icon icon="users"></e-icon> Cat 4 <f-icon icon="caret-down" class = "downNavArrow rotate-reset"></f-icon>
      </span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="tabs-1" id="tabs-1-5" divId="div5" value="360003487197">
    <label class="tabs__title" for="tabs-1-5">
      <span class="tabs__separator">
        <f-icon icon="media-rich"></f-icon>Cat 5 <f-icon icon="caret-down" class = "downNavArrow rotate-reset"></f-icon>
      </span>
    </label>
    <div class="tabs__panel">
      <div class="tabs__panel__content" id="div0">

      </div>
      <div class="tabs__panel__content" id="div1">

      </div>
      <div class="tabs__panel__content" id="div2">

      </div>
      <div class="tabs__panel__content" id="div3">

      </div>
      <div class="tabs__panel__content" id="div4">

      </div>
      <div class="tabs__panel__content" id="div5">

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can I append the request itself instead of the id?.
The ```summonSct()```  function takes this 
```var sct_select = $( "input[type=radio][name=tabs-1]:checked" ).val();``` and adds it in the url thus changing the content that is being fetched.